# Mobile lite version on my android device

Tags: mobile

Can some one provide the steps for the configuration of the mobile lite for the android application after installation of the sales force mobile lite.

I have created the data set but still i cannot see the data set in the mobile device.

Regards,

Sushma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I used mobile lite but from recollection Mobile lite doesn't support custom datasets. It does allow you to create them but they will only work with a full mobile license.